# Most efficient way to look for the last digit of a number?

Tags: python

I recently had a question in a Python exam where we were asked to check for numbers to be ending in 8 and I came across two ways and I was wondering which one was the most efficient or if there was an even better way to do so.

(If n is the desired number)
So, method 1:

```
if n % 10 == 8:
    //do stuff here
```

Method 2:

```
if str(n)[-1] == 8:
    //do stuff here
```

Comment: A *very* crude (actually borderline misleading) way to think about it is how many operations are happening. Despite Method 2 being beautifully easily represented in Python, it's nasty! You're first converting an integer to a string, then indexing that string, then comparing the result against 8. Although mod 10 is harder than mod 2^k  (k arbitrary), it's still much cheaper than dealing with the string equivalent.

Comment: Method 2 would need to be `str(n)[-1] == '8'` since you converted the number to a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could easily test this yourself with Python's built-in [`timeit.timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit) function:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> n = 12345678
>>> timeit("n % 10 == 8", "from __main__ import n")
0.45508130223254284
>>> timeit("str(n)[-1] == '8'", "from __main__ import n")
1.689859186013905
>>>
```

As you can see from the results above, the first solution is very efficient and outperforms the second by almost four times.

Comment: Should be `== '8'` in the string approach.

Answer (score 4):

For more fun and excitement in addition to iCodez answer, you can use the `dis` module to see what the difference in instructions is:

```
wayne@wango ~ ⚘ python3.4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               14:24:49
Python 3.4.0 (default, Mar 25 2014, 15:24:33) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('n % 10 == 8')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (n)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (10)
              6 BINARY_MODULO
              7 LOAD_CONST               1 (8)
             10 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis('str(n)[-1] == 8')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (str)
              3 LOAD_NAME                1 (n)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 (-1)
             12 BINARY_SUBSCR
             13 LOAD_CONST               1 (8)
             16 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             19 RETURN_VALUE
```

If I were to make a guess, I'd say the major time difference has to do with the string conversion. And a quick test:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> n = 12345678
>>> m = "12345678"
>>> timeit("n % 10 == 8", "from __main__ import n")
0.09333206800511107
>>> timeit("m[-1] == '8'", "from __main__ import m")
0.05890634500246961
>>>
```

Shows this to be the case.

Additionally in your code, the second example would always equate to `False`, since a string will never `==` a number.

Comment: what does all the `dis` output mean?

Comment: [`dis` "supports the analysis of CPython bytecode by disassembling it."](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) That is what your program gets turned into before the Python interpreter can run it.

Comment: I know what dis is, I meant what is the interpretation for this particular comparison.